# How to change the url

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to change the URL of the update operation. The end point of the URL should be gotten from an input. How can I achieve this? The following doesn't work.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
       $.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return {"issue":o};
};
```

```html
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Issue ID * &nbsp;</label>
        <select class="form-control selectclass" id="issueid"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Tracker * &nbsp;</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="tracker" id="tracker">
          <option value="1">Bug</option>
          <option value="2">Feature</option>
          <option value="3">Support</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Subject &nbsp;</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Issue Subject" name="subject" id="subject">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
    </div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
  </form>
```

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
            var x=document.getElementById('issueid').value;
            $.ajax({
                type : 'PUT',
                
                url: 'http://localhost/redmine/issues'+ x +'.json',
               
                
                contentType:'application/json',
                 
                data:JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()), // post data || get data
                success : function(msg, status, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(msg, status, jqXHR);
                    
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
            console.log(x);
         });
   
});
```

Inputs are gotten from a form and sent to Redmine API. URL should look like below, `http://localhost/redmine/issues/2.json`

Comment: what's your server side? Why are you using PUT over a json file?

Comment: Can you add the HTML structure?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Do you get an error? What error? Do you get different behavior than you expected? Do you have an element with ID `issueid` on the form?

Comment: how should the URL look like after getting the value from input?

Comment: Please check the above. URL should look like,
http://localhost/redmine/issues/2.json

Comment: The `id="issueid"` select doesn't have any options in it. Are you sure you didn't mean to use the `id="tracker"` select?

Comment: data to select is gotten from a GET operation. And data has append to the select id.

Comment: Did you forget to add **submit** id to submit button in the form?And change the url to : `url: 'http://localhost/redmine/issues/'+ x +'.json'`.

Comment: added the id, this is the error in console,
`PUT http://localhost/redmine/issues.json 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Because the id, is not getting added in the URL.

Comment: Open on the console, what errors do you get? Underneath `var x=document.getElementById('issueid').value;` add `console.log('http://localhost/redmine/issues'+ x +'.json')` - What does is tell you?

Comment: @mars, that's because as I said in my previous comment, the `id="issueid"` select doesn't have any options at the moment you are trying to read its value and the `x` variable is simply empty. Or maybe the `<option>` elements that were dynamically added to it don't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: @Darin, I am doing GET operation concurrently to fill the options 
`$.ajax({
      type : 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://localhost/redmine/issues.json',
     
      success: function(results){
                  

            $.each(results.issues, function(i,value) {
              $('.selectclass').append(
                '<option value="">'+ value.id + '<option>'
               

                ); 
            });

        }
    });`

Comment: yeah but you didn't set any value. You are just setting it to an empty string: `value=""`. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you, fixed everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dynamically populating your `id="issueid"` select make sure that you properly set the `value` attribute of the options:

```
$('.selectclass').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.id + '<option>');
```

Also fix the url for your next AJAX request by adding a trailing `/` after `issues`:

```
url: 'http://localhost/redmine/issues/' + x + '.json'
```